# How to run 2 for loops sequentially using Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to rearrange the tab order in angular. The reason I need to run 2 loops is because I'm using mongodb which doesn't allow duplicate values. So during the first loop I'm resetting the value to random number then setting the correct order index value. However, when I try to run the code below its not getting executed sequentially.

```
updateTabsOrder(){
    for(let i=0; i<this.rearrangedTabs.length; i++){
        this._dataService.updateTabsOrder(this.rearrangedTabs[i].id, Math.random())
        .subscribe((response) => {
          console.log('a');
        })
      }
    for(let i=0; i<this.rearrangedTabs.length; i++){
        this._dataService.updateTabsOrder(this.rearrangedTabs[i].id, i+1)
        .subscribe((response) => {
          console.log('b');
        })
      }
    }
```

**Service:**

```
updateTabsOrder(tab_id, order_index){
        return this.http.put(this.base_url + 'manufacturer_tabs/' + tab_id, {
            order_index: order_index
        })
        .map(data => {
            return data;
        });
    }
```

/* JSON */

```
[
    {
        "order_index": 2,
        "tab_name": "tab 1",
        "createdAt": "2018-04-24T12:46:41.890Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-04-24T14:38:05.138Z",
        "manufacturers": "5acf62cf080d700c2209d40b",
        "id": "5adf2731366e1a0e4085a4f3"
    },
    {
        "order_index": 1,
        "tab_name": "tab 2",
        "createdAt": "2018-04-24T12:46:47.985Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-04-24T14:09:15.919Z",
        "manufacturers": "5acf62cf080d700c2209d40b",
        "id": "5adf2737366e1a0e4085a4f4"
    }
]
```

The above code outputs as:

```
b
a
b
```

Instead of

```
a
a
b
b
```

Comment: It's not executed sequentially, and never will be, because it's _asynchronous_. You need to redesign your logic in order to deal with that.

Comment: @JeremyThille Thanks for your reply. Could you please provide an example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use promise all to wait for first batch and for second batch. I'm using `map()` for simplicity.

```
async updateTabsOrder(){
    // make sure that tabs is an Array and we can call .map
    const rearrangedTabs = Array.from(this.rearrangedTabs);

    // run the first batch of requests to the server
    const randomizingPromises = rearrangedTabs.map(tab => 
             this._dataService.updateTabsOrder(tab.id, Math.random()).toPromise()
    );

    // wait until all requests from the first batch to the server finish
    await Promise.all(randomizingPromises).then(() => console.log("finished randomizing order"));

    // run the second batch of requests to the server   
    const finalPromises = rearrangedTabs.map((tab, i) =>
            this._dataService.updateTabsOrder(tab.id, i+1).toPromise()
    );

    // wait until all requests from the second batch to the server finish
    await Promise.all(finalPromises).then(() => console.log("finished final order"));

    console.log("finished all");
}
```

This will be evaluted in two steps:

1. Send all the random data at once. Wait for each of the randomizing request to finish.
2. Send all correct order data at once. Wait for each of the request to finish.

Comment: I'm getting an error `Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.rearrangedTabs.map is not a function`

Comment: Is `this.rearrangedTabs` array? If not, you need to wrap it into `Array.from(this.rearrangedTabs).map()`

Comment: I also had same incorrectly named variables in my code, sorry.

Comment: Yes `this.rearrangedTabs` is already an array. Not sure what's causing the error.

Comment: Seems like the `this.rearrangedTabs` is `undefined`. Is the value set before you call `updateTabsOrder`?

Comment: When I do console.log(this.rearrangedTabs) its outputting as a HTMLCollection.  `HTMLCollection(2) [div#5adf2731366e1a0e4085a4f3.tab.ng-star-inserted, div#5adf2737366e1a0e4085a4f4.tab.ng-star-inserted, 5adf2731366e1a0e4085a4f3: div#5adf2731366e1a0e4085a4f3.tab.ng-star-inserted, 5adf2737366e1a0e4085a4f4: div#5adf2737366e1a0e4085a4f4.tab.ng-star-inserted]`

Comment: Means that it is not an `Array`. You need to adjust the code so `const randomizingPromises = Array.from(this.rearrangedTabs).map(...)`

Answer (score -2):

Javascript it's an Asynchronous Language.

```
updateTabsOrder() {

    this.rearrangedTabs.map((item, index, object) => {
        console.log(item.id + ' ' + (index + 1));
        this._dataService.updateTabsOrder(item.id, Math.random())
            .subscribe((response) => {
                console.log('a');
            });
        return item;
    }).map((item, index, object) => {
        console.log(item.id + ' ' + (index + 1));

        this._dataService.updateTabsOrder(item.id, index + 1)
            .subscribe((response) => {
                console.log('b');
            });
        return item;
    });
}
```

Comment: This will not be called in sequence. There's no awaiting for the intermediate results.

Comment: If it was called in sequence, the first .map returns the next array to be traversed.

Comment: But you cannot start calling the second map until all of the requests from the first map have finished.